# How do I triangulate a point from 3 segments, rather than from 3 points?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a real-world acoustics problem that I'm trying to solve for some work related R&D. Hopefully you big brained folks can explain down to me. :) I'm good at visualizing math concepts, but I lack any substantial experience, save perhaps g/FooBar. So, sans elegance:


Edit: Using the below descriptions, I'm attempting to model a room with people talking into mics while facing the center of the room. The segment variability models the potential distance to a mic that the respective person might be, as people in this environment will often change their position from leaning into a mic to leaning back in their chair. I realize these constraints limit beyond actual potential for where a person might be physically located relative to their mic. However, I picked the constraints because 1. they cover the vast majority of cases 2. I am actually interested in learning how to solve the problem as described 3. the output I am trying to achieve is for *estimating* time delays to compare to cross-correlegrams, so imperfection is quite alright.


Let's start with a basic open acoustic space, and represent its length and width using a 2d grid. For simplicity, let's assume our origin (0, 0) marks the center of the room.

Place 3 microphones (a,b,c) at random in the room.
Imagine onto our 2d space 3 rays (a1,b1,c1) that start at the origin, and cross each of the microphone coordinates.

Now let's add 3 sound sources (A,B,C) to the space with the following constraints:

- A,B,C respectively fall on rays a1, b1, and c1
- the distance to each sound source A,B,C from 0,0 is > the distance to the respective mics
- apply some arbitrary limit (L) to the distance between respective sources and mics

So, based on the title of this question, the 3 segments start at the mic coords a,b,c, and overlap rays a1,b1,c1 each for a length of L. The sound sources A,B,C could fall anywhere on their respective segments.

How do I use the (precise) varying sound arrival times at the mics a,b,c to determine the relative coordinates of the mics when I don't know exactly where the sound sources A,B,C are located, only that the sources A,B,C are constrained to fall on the segments a1,b1,c1?

To be overtly concise, we do not start with exact knowledge of the distances A-a, B-b, C-c, rather the data we have is (A:a-b,a-c)(B:b-a,b-c)(C:c-a,c-b).

Edit: "(A:a-b,a-c)" is a made-up convention. Neither math nor physics. In this example, I just mean to indicate that for source A signal, we know the difference in arrival time between a-b, and a-c.

Thanks for the help!
-Sobel

Comment: What does the notation "(A:a-b,a-c)(B:b-a,b-c)(C:c-a,c-b)" mean?

Comment: Do you know the time-of-flight from source A to mics a, b, and c?  (i.e., from the amount that the audio signal produced by source A is delayed at each mic?)

Comment: Are you open to solutions that involve adding a few more mics?

Comment: I don't think the setup is very realistic.  Why should segments connecting the sound sources (A,B,C) and the the mics (a,b,c) all intersect at one point ??

Comment: @D.W. Sorry, I'll add some more detail there. It means that while we don't know the exact location of the sound source, we do know the difference in signal arrival times at the 2nd & 3rd mics, compared to the signal arrival time at the source's respective primary mic. <br> "(A:a-b,a-c)" was intended to indicate that, considering signal from source "A", we know "a-b" and "a-c". It was an entirely made-up convention, and I thought the colon would indicate as much, but really, it was just a bad idea. :)

Comment: @D.W. We do not know the time of flight from source A to a, b, or c. We only know the difference between a, b, and c.

Comment: @D.W. There are a few thousand rooms like this that I'm working on, and the number of mics in each room is determined by the functional requirements of the AV system. The number of mics per room ranges from 2 to 13. I did request an additional omnidirectional mic at one point, mainly to attempt to reduce the processing requirements on the noise reduction algorithms and thus alleviate some truncated spoken words. I *might know where you're going with the question, relating to general algebra and solvability? I'm eager to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @ofcourse Sound sources = humans talking. Each person has their own mic. Everyone is facing the center of the room. The segments indicate the potential range of distance that a person might be from their microphone. In _reality_, it is possible that a person moves laterally, or turns their head, or whatever. But the vast majority of the variances that I'm trying to account for is from folks leaning into the mics vs leaning back in their chair. It is also possible, and probable that some human-mic axes do not face the center of the room. But again, I'm trying to solve for the bulk of cases.

Comment: @ofcourse And yes, I could have put all that in the question. But the real problem is considerably more complex, and I was really just looking for an answer to the question that I asked, using constraints that target the circumstances that occur in the acoustic spaces the majority of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heuristically, if you have 4 mics, there might be just barely enough information to determine the placement of the points.  With 5 mics, heuristically, I would expect that a unique solution should exist.  With only 3 mics, I'm pretty sure there is not enough information to resolve the location of the points.

Here is the heuristic: if you have $n$ mics, then there are effectively $3n$ unknowns.  (2 unknowns for each mic for the $x,y$ coordinates of the mic, and 1 more unknown for the distance from the mic to its corresponding sound source.)  Also there are $(n-1)n$ observations (for each mic, there are $n-1$ differences in sound arrival timing).

I don't know of a simple algebraic formula to recover the location of the points, but this could be formulated as an instance of an optimization problem, and then you could use any off-the-shelf optimization problem to solve it.  In particular, let $\delta_{ij}$ be the difference: distance from source $i$ to mic $j$ minus distance from source $i$ to mic $i$.  (This can be obtained from the difference in arrival times, by multiplying by the speed of sound.)  Let $(x_i,y_i)$ denote the position of mic $i$, and $s_i$ be the distance from mic $i$ to source $i$.  Formulate the following objective function:

$$\Phi = \sum_{i,j} (\sqrt{(x'_i-x_j)^2 + (y'_i-y_j)^2} - s_i - \delta_{ij})^2,$$

where

$$(x'_i,y'_i) = [1 + {s_i \over \sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2}}] \cdot (x_i,y_i).$$

This formula ensures that $(x'_i,y'_i)$ is the location of source $i$.  Now, we are given the observations $\delta_{ij}$, and the goal is to find the values of the variables $(x_i,y_i),s_i$.  Notice that the correct values of these values make $\Phi=0$, and for all values we have $\Phi \ge 0$.  Therefore, we can obtain a good guess at the location of all points by finding values for $(x_i,y_i),s_i$ that minimize the value of $\Phi$.

Locating the points thus reduces to solving an optimization problem in a $3n$ dimensional space.  Solving this optimization problem might be non-trivial, but one possible approach is to choose random initial values for all the variables, then apply Newton's method to minimize $\Phi$.  Repeat 1000 times for 1000 different random initializations, and keep the best solution found.  There might be better optimization algorithms for this problem.

I don't know whether this will work in practice, once you take into account noise and the challenges of clock synchronization.  I would guess that the more mics you have, the better the chance you have.  Probably the only way to find out whether it will work is to give it a try and see.

Another challenge is that in real life, the sound sources and mics are in 3D, not in a 2D plane.  So you might need to account for that.  This might require even more mics.  Also, another challenge is that you might have echos and other effects that make it challenging to identify arrival time and distance accurately.  Finally, I'm not convinced that everyone is all facing the origin.  For instance, if you have a large meeting with people sitting around a rectangular table, the sound sources will not lie on the line joining the mic and the origin, because people are facing perpendicular to the edge of the table, not towards the center of the table.  But maybe those are all manageable, I don't know.